# How to stop text at screen borders?

Tags: assembly

I'm making this little program where I have to move an asterisk around the screen. The problem is that every time it hits a border, I get an extra asterisk. Any help in how to get rid of that extra asterisk? It's a really simple program.

Here's my code so far:

```
.model small
.stack 256

.data
row  db 10                       ;Save the initial cursor coordinates in
col  db 40                       ;col and row.
msg1 db "*",'$'                  ;Asterisk to be used by the program.
msg2 db " ",'$'

mSetCursor macro                 ;Macro for placing the cursor in the screen.
;pre-conditions
;
;    None
;
;post-conditions
;
;    Asterisks will be printed on the screen,
;    depending on the location of the cursor.

push ax                       
push bx
push dx

mov bh,0
mov ah,2
mov dh,row
mov dl,col
int 10h

pop dx
pop bx
pop ax
endm

.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

mov ax,03                     ;Clean the screen.
int 10h

start:
mSetCursor                    ;Call the macro in charge of placing
                              ;the asterisk on the screen.
mov ah,10h
int 16h

cmp ah,2dh                    ;Using the scan code of the letter X, we end
je exit                       ;the program once the "X" key is pressed.

cmp ah,0bh                ;Using the scan code of the number 0, we clean
je clear                      ;the screen once the "0" key is pressed.

cmp ah,4bh                    ;Using the scan code of the left arrow,
je left                       ;we use the left arrow key to move the asterisk left.

cmp ah,48h                    ;Using the scan code of the up arrow,
je up                         ;we use the up arrow key to move the asterisk up.

cmp ah,4Dh                    ;Using the scan code of the right arrow, 
je right                      ;we use the right arrow key to move the asterisk right.

cmp ah,50h                    ;Using the scan code of the down arrow,
je down                       ;we use the down arrow key to move the asterisk down.

mov ah,9                  ;Code in charge of receiving the fifth message
mov dx, offset msg2           ;This code ensures that nothing happens while
int 21h                       ;keys that aren't arrow keys, 0, or X (quit) are pressed.
jmp start

left:                         ;We receive the asterisk, and decrease the value of col
mov ah,9                      ;This starts the leftward movement of the asterisk.
mov dx, offset msg1           ;Finally, we skip to the Start label.
int 21h                        
dec col

cmp col,00                ;Disallow that the asterisk move past the
je right                  ;left side of the screen.

jmp start                      

right:                        ;Receive the asterisk, and increase the value of col.
mov ah,9                      ;This starts the rightward movement of the asterisk.
mov dx, offset msg1           ;Finally, we skip to the Start label.
int 21h
inc col

cmp col,79                    ;Disallow that the asterisk move past the 
je left                   ;right side of the screen.

jmp start

down:                         ;We receive the asterisk and increase the value of row.
mov ah,9                      ;This starts the downward movement of the asterisk.
mov dx, offset msg1           ;Finally, we jump to the Start label.
int 21h
inc row

cmp row,24                ;Disallow that the asterisk move past the
je up                     ;bottom of the screen.

jmp start

up:                           ;We receive the asterisk, and decrease the value of row.
mov ah,9                      ;This starts the upward movement of the asterisk.
mov dx, offset msg1           ;Finally, we jump to the Start label.
int 21h
dec row

cmp row,-1                ;Disallow that the asterisk move past the
je down                   ;top of the screen.

jmp start

clear:
mov ax,03                     ;Clean the screen.
int 10h
jmp start

exit:                         ;Label that lets us end the program.
mov ah,4ch
int 21h

main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is when it reaches an edge, it receives two interrupts to place asterisk. To elaborate, suppose the cursor is at right edge. Then right key is pressed. Now it will jump to label `right`. It'll place an asterisk at current cursor position. Then increment `col` and jump to label `left`. There it'll decrement `col` to prevent going over the edge. But label left also contains an interrupt to place asterisk resulting in two `*`.

To prevent this, instead of first increment then decrement just skip the `inc col` if an edge is reached. For example your `right` label is modified to

```
right:                        ;Receive the asterisk, and increase the value of col.
mov ah,9                      ;This starts the rightward movement of the asterisk.
mov dx, offset msg1           
int 21h

cmp col,78                    ;Disallow that the asterisk move past the 
je start                      ;right side of the screen.

inc col

jmp start                     ;Finally, we skip to the Start label.
```

You'll have to do this for other three also. Change comparison value `cmp col, 78` depending on where you want to stop.

There, I just debugged your code and it was fun. :)